# sleep() misbehaves with MessageBox

Tags: tizen

Created a Ui app with a Button. On Click of the button with in OnActionPerformed() of MainForm, created and launched a MessageBox with a 3 seconds delay. Soon after that i kept sleep for about 10 seconds. MessageBox disappears only after 13 seconds i.e., 3 + 10 (MessageBox wait seconds + Sleep seconds)

Code snippet:

```
{
    MessageBox messageBox;
    messageBox.Construct(L"MessageBox Title", L"MessageBox Sample Code.", MSGBOX_STYLE_OK, 3000);

    int modalResult = 0;

    messageBox.ShowAndWait(modalResult);

    sleep(10);
}
```

Please clarify.

Thanks

Anil

Comment: The numbers you mention in your description don't seem to match the code.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs Michael. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no chance to update the UI (i.e. closing the message box) for the platform because you are not returning control to the platform between messageBox.ShowAndWait(modalResult); and sleep(10);. And unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to return the control to the platform (at least as of Tizen 2.2) such as Application.DoEvents() in the .NET framework.

Generally, you should do a time consuming process (such as sleep(10)) in the other thread.